# How do I output a 'confirmed' message on my registration page after a user has clicked submit?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have a nodejs server, and have created a registration page in html. When the submit button is clicked, the server I created receives the input and checks the values.

If the user has been added to the database, I want the register page to be sent back with a new message saying "The user has been added".

Right now I use "res.sendFile()" and send the page back again, but I want to do that PLUS a new message element.

Here's part of the **javascript** code in the server:

```
    console.log(req.body);

    const { email, username, password, passwordConfirm } = req.body;

    db.query("SELECT email FROM playerinfo where email = ?", [email], (error, results) => {
        if (error) console.log(error);

        if (results.length > 0) {
            return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/register.html'), );
        }


        db.query("INSERT INTO playerinfo VALUES ?", 
{ username: username, password: password, email: email }, (error, results) => {
            if (error) console.log(error);
            else {
                console.log(results);

                return res.sendFile(path.join(__dirname, '../client/register.html'));
            }
        });
    });
}
```

Here's the HTML for the **register page**:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>

<head>
    <title>Create an account</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="style/menustyle.css">
    <link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.0-beta3/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"
        integrity="sha384-eOJMYsd53ii+scO/bJGFsiCZc+5NDVN2yr8+0RDqr0Ql0h+rP48ckxlpbzKgwra6" crossorigin="anonymous">
</head>

<body>

    <nav>
        <h3>User Login Test</h3>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
            <li><a href="/login">Log in</a></li>
            <li><a href="/register">Register</a></li>
        </ul>
    </nav>

    <div id='register-box' class="card" style="width: 18rem;">
        <h3 class="card-title">Register</h3>
        <div class="card-body">
            <form action="/auth/register" method="POST">
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="player-email" class="form-label">Email address</label>
                    <input type="email" class="form-control" id="player-email" aria-describedby="emailHelp"
                        name='email'>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="player-username" class="form-label">Username</label>
                    <input type="text" class="form-control" id="player-username" name='username'>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="player-password" class="form-label">Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="player-password" name='password'>
                </div>
                <div class="mb-3">
                    <label for="player-password-confirm" class="form-label">Confirm Password</label>
                    <input type="password" class="form-control" id="player-password-confirm" name='passwordConfirm'>
                </div>
                

                <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Submit</button>
            </form>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: Few tips: 1. sanitize your SQL query since your implementation is subject to injection. 2. find a better way than console.log when responding to errors. 3. don't use console.log in production as it will blow your memory without you noticing it until drive will be 100% full

Comment: use a template engine, then instead of `res.sendFile`, do `res.render`, is [in the docs](http://expressjs.com/en/api.html#res.render). Or personally, id use js clientside validation, then post off with ajax and do serverside validation and respond with json, its better ux

Comment: @YonatanVainer please point out the sql injection, can't see it myself. What's wrong with console.log() for debugging? Also, it doesn't write to log files, pm2 does that, OP didn't say is using pm2

Comment: @LawrenceCherone you are right regarding the SQL. I didn't know that passing an object escaping it. Thank you. Regarding the logging, someone once told me "friends don't let friend's debug with console.log" and I believe it's something wrong newcomers take with them to production.

Comment: I am relatively new to js, guess you could tell, haha. Still trying to find my bearings involving account creation and the likes. Regarding the console.log, i was following a tutorial where they did that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Why are you making it in that way?
Is a requirement or is your decision ?
I think you have a couple of ways to do this.

1. You can use ajax from client and get an json response from the server. With that you will have a better experience in your registration web and you avoid to reload all the page and send back the page again.
2. If you need reload all the  page and send back again from the server, you can  use some template manager like mustache and parse the html content before to send it, or simply have two different html. Anyway, I think that is not a good idea.

Comment: I was following a tutorial where they were using hbs instead of html and got lost when they started using handbrakes. Thank you very much, I will check out AJAX and continue from there.

Comment: Ajax today is very simple, check the `fetch` method of the javascript web API. and mark it as solved if was usefull for you